# Changing Font in PowerPoint with Input Box VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to change the font of all the text in a PowerPoint Presentation depending on what font a user inputs but when I try it doesn't change anything. Where am I going wrong? Is there a nicer way to implement this... say with a font dropdown box or something? As I want to also implement the font size/bold/italic etc too. Thanks!

```
Sub ChangeFont()

Dim bpFontName As String

        bpFontName = InputBox("What font would you like to change EVERYTHING to?")


    With ActivePresentation
        For Each Slide In .Slides
            For Each Shape In Slide.Shapes
                With Shape
                    If .HasTextFrame Then
                        If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = bpFontName
                            'Set font size below
                            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 30
                            'Set if you want the font bold below - msoFalse = no
                            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
                            'Set if you want the font bold below - msoFalse = no
                            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Italic = msoTrue
                        End If
                    End If
                End With
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you set a breakpoint at `bpFintName = ... ` and step through the code with F8?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you didn't dim some of your variables, and it's bad practice to use reserved words (Slide, Shape) as variable names. I've fixed it like so:

```
Sub ChangeFont()

Dim bpFontName As String
Dim oSld as Slide
Dim oSh as Shape

        bpFontName = InputBox("What font would you like to change EVERYTHING to?")


    With ActivePresentation
        For Each oSld In .Slides
            For Each oSh In oSld.Shapes
                With oSh
                    If .HasTextFrame Then
                        If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = bpFontName
                            'Set font size below
                            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 30
                            'Set if you want the font bold below - msoFalse = no
                            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
                            'Set if you want the font bold below - msoFalse = no
                            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Italic = msoTrue
                        End If
                    End If
                End With
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```